# transpose data and remove duplicates on excel or sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, excel

I have the following data:

```
First   Name        State   Plan_Code
Sonia   Laurelton   NY      OXF-PL3-P
Sonia   Laurelton   NY      OXF-PL3-P
Sonia   Laurelton   NY      MLR-P
Sonia   Laurelton   NY      CL-HLTH1-P
Sonia   Laurelton   NY      MET-DEN-P
Sonia   Laurelton   NY      MET-DEN-P
Sonia   Laurelton   NY      DAV-VISC-P
```

How Can I have my data look like this with a sql statement or an excel statement (doesn't matter whichever is easier)

```
First    Name      State OXF-PL3-P MLR-P CL-HLTH1-P MET-DEN-P DAV-VISC-P
Sonia    Laurelton NY    2         1     1          2         1
```

Comment: hi, debflav, sorry, i meant to keep the question short and simple.  I did tried the special copy and transpose paste code on excel, but it didn't work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a simple pivot table, see [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-HA102840046.aspx) using count as values.

Comment: thanks stef got it working playing around with pivot